# .ico File not deletable on Win7 x64,why?

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, file-permissions, icons

I have a computer running WIndows 7 x64, and I recently noticed that Files with an extension .ico on USB sticks cannot be deleted. I then tried the same on another PC, and the .ico file was properly deleted.

Can anybody think of any program that might block the .ico File from being deleted? I do not get an error message, but after a short time, the file is back there.

This is so strange...

Comment: How big is the file? Maybe it's a virus trying to spread, looking like an .ico file...

Comment: Is it any ICO on any USB stick that doing this, or just a specific ICO and/or USB stick? Can you replicate the problem at will? Does it behave the same way while booted in Safe Mode? How about in normal mode, but while logged in as a different user?

Comment: Hopefully, the .ico files continuously getting recreated. Have you tried scanning the USB stick using any Antivirus programs? and ensure, no infections. Sometimes, this could be due to browser cache and temp internet files.

Comment: If the file is back, then you are indeed deleting it, but something else seems to be checking periodically and ensuring that file is there - for whatever reason.